# Using touchscreen for right-click drag

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, gestures

I just got a Surface Pro 3, and am trying out some older games designed for mouse control. I found that many of these would be playable even without the type cover (i.e., touchscreen only), except for the need of a right-click drag for panning (e.g., Anno 1404).

Does anyone know a gesture for this? Or a tool that could be used? Ideally, two-finger tap would be a right click (this works only on the touchpad, not the screen), and two-finger drag would be a right-click drag.

A solution using no more than Autohotkey would be great, but I am not averse to trying other tools.